# How much type-inference can you possibly cram out of vanilla PHP?

Tags: php, type-inference

I want to make a type-inferring linter for a subset of PHP, but am unsure about how much type information you can get out of it without having to enforce phpdoc annotations or similar. Consider this example:

```
function a() {
  b(10); // This is wrong, but we don't know the type of b()
}

function b($c) {
   print($c . " hallo"); // Only allow concatenations with strings
}
```

Without the in OCaml present `and` for mutual recursion, things have to be defined in order of use. The way to get around it is to make a two-stage type-checker, where the first stage checks interfaces, but type-inferring needs to go through the body of the functions.

One way to get around this is to enforce phpdoc docblocks:

```
function a() {
  b(10); // Type error: b() expects a string
}

/**
 * @param string $c
 */
function b($c) {
   print($c . " hallo");
}
```

Enforcing docblocks to be used in type-checking feels... wrong. Is there any way around this? Of course the scalar type-hints v5, using `declare(strict_types=1)`, would allow scalar type-hints in function signatures, but that's too far into the future.

**Edit**: I'm stupid, `b()` could of course be inferred from it's usage in `a()`, so we would have:

```
function a() {
  b(10); // b() inferred to int -> void
}

function b($c) {
   print($c . " hallo"); // Wrong, $c used as a string
}
```

Comment: You can also generate type annotations by checking the types at runtime. [MonkeyType](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType) does this in Python, so it's probably possible in PHP as well.

Comment: You can also use the Reflection API to [get a function's parameter types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php) and [return type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getreturntype.php).

Answer (score 3):

You could create classes that represent the scalar values you want to type hint.

```
class String {
  protected $string;

  public function __construct($value) {
    if (!is_string($value)) {
      throw new Exception('Not a string');
    }
    $this->string = $value;
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return $this->string;
  }
}
```

Then in your function declaration:

```
function b(String $c) {
  ...
}

b(new String('Some String'));
```

Comment: This is definitely one option, and I thought about it, but maybe it will be too clumsy, especially for numbers. Also, any comment about my edit above?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt I don't think that would work. What if you have multiple usages? Which one would make it the correct one? That would depend on the order that files were included and that could get messy.

Comment: @JuanMendes, then you would have a type-error, I suppose. :) The interesting part is when a function takes an object implementing an interface, or sub-classed objects.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt I would not want to use a linting system where the parameter types are inferred by how they are called, seems backwards to me, just my two cents :)

Comment: @JuanMendes, that's how ML works, according to the folks in the IRC. Oh well.